# Resize and rename PNG, JPG or GIF file with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, resize, rename

is there any way, using PHP, that you can resize an image sent from a HTML form's WIDTH (Only PNG, JPG and GIF) to a max value of let's say 500px (so if the file is 350px wide there isn't any stretching), and rename it to a random 15 character name (e.g. "e19gy675jo5el7g.png") and save it to the image/ directory?

I have some code already but it doesn't resize the file and allows all file types to be uploaded (it only renames the file to a random name). I don't want to use the accept="image/*" HTML code in the form so if you could help me find a PHP solution that would be great.

Here's my PHP code...

```
    <?php
 function findexts ($filename) 
 { 
 $filename = strtolower($filename) ; 
 $exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ; 
 $n = count($exts)-1; 
 $exts = $exts[$n]; 
 return $exts; 
 }     
 $ext = findexts ($_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ;   
 $ran = rand () ;   
 $ran2 = $ran.".";   
 $target = "image/";
 $target = $target . $ran2.$ext;   
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
 echo "The file has been uploaded as ".$ran2.$ext;
 } 
 else
 {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 }
 ?>
```

And here's my HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
<div>
<input name="uploaded" type="file" />
</div>
<br>
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the complicated question, I'm just quite new with PHP :-)

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: the answer to the three questions is yes, and the above code you do the last one, so where's the attempt at the first two?

Comment: I've tried to add the first two in but I don't know where to add them in to the code :( As in I don't know where the resizing and image uploading code goes in the PHP document :(

Comment: There are loads/tons of examples out there (1st result from google http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/), I suggest you give one a go & if you get an error let s know & we can help.

Comment: I read the whole page and although the code does work I don't know how to make it work via a form from a html page and then save to the directory image/. And also I don't know how to add all PHP codes (renaming and only supporting png, jpg and gif), in to one so that the PHP form does all three at the same time. Sorry for being a bother I'm just so confused on what to do!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the whole code but you can do it by GD library of PHP.Use

```
getimagesize($filename)
```

TO get the image details and check the width using it.If width is less than 500 then do not resize.

Link that may help you: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/210603-uploaded-image-change-width-and-height/